# How to count from a table based on another table

Tags: sql, join, count

I have 4 Tables,  I don't need the 'Questions' Table, but I just put it there so you'd know where i got the Question ID in the other tables.

```
Questions
--------
ID 
Question


Question_Options
--------
ID 
Question_ID
Option_Label


Session
--------------
ID    
GENDER   


Session_Answers
-----------------
ID
Session_ID
Option_ID
Question_ID
```

I calculated the following: the number of votes for each option from a certain question, like so

```
SELECT Q.Option_Label as Choice, COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Session_Answers S WHERE S.Option_ID = Q.ID),0) as Votes
FROM Question_Options Q 
     INNER JOIN Session_Answers S
       ON Q.Question_ID = S.Question_ID
WHERE Q.Question_ID = 10114<---the Question ID
GROUP BY Q.ID,Q.option_label
```

What I want to do, is add a new column to the query that calculates the number of males who have chosen each option based on the Session Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that :

```
SELECT QO.Question_ID, QO.Option_Label as Choice, COUNT(*) as VotesMale
FROM Question_Options QO 
LEFT JOIN Session_Answers SA ON QO.ID = SA.Option_ID
JOIN [Session] S ON S.ID = SA.Session_ID AND S.Gender = 'M'
WHERE QO.Question_ID = 10114<---the Question ID
GROUP BY QO.Question_ID, QO.Option_label
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add extra count from the Session table filtered with Gender.

```
SELECT Q.Option_Label as Choice, COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Session_Answers SA WHERE
SA.Option_ID = Q.ID),0) as Votes,
COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Session SM WHERE
S.Session_ID = SM.Session_ID AND Gender='M'),0) as MalesSessions
FROM Question_Options Q 
    INNER JOIN Session_Answers S
    ON Q.Question_ID = S.Question_ID
WHERE Q.Question_ID = 10114 ---the Question ID
GROUP BY Q.ID,Q.option_label
```